# Get individual array Items

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am reading data from a firebase DB and storing it in a message object, How can I then access each element in that array? i.e how can I use the City string as I wish to assign that to a label. Same with each other element in the array.

```
    firebaseDB.collection("user").document(key).collection("address").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        }
        else {
            self.dataArr.removeAll()
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                let msgdata = document.data() as! [String:Any]
                var msgObj = Details()
                if let city = msgdata["city"] as? String {

                    msgObj.city = city
                }

                if let country = msgdata["country"] as? String {

                    msgObj.country = country
                }
                if let county = msgdata["county"] as? String {

                    msgObj.county = county
                }

                if let lineOne = msgdata["lineOne"] as? String {

                    msgObj.lineOne = lineOne
                }
                if let lineTwo = msgdata["lineTwo"] as? String {

                    msgObj.lineTwo = lineTwo
                }
                if let postCode = msgdata["postCode"] as? String {

                    msgObj.postCode = postCode
                }
                self.dataArr.append(msgObj)

            }


        }
    }
```

I will need to access each element as I have another function which will take each element and place it on a label in my ViewController

Something like this is what I wish to have

```
func DisplayAddress(){
 city.text = city
 postCode.text = postCode
}
```

Comment: You access an element of the array using it's index, and a parameter fo the element using `.` operator followed the property. But, you haven't explained how or where you want to access it, which will help you get a better solution.

Comment: I wish to access it in the same Class just a different function :)

Comment: Which element of the array do you want to access?

Comment: Well I will need to access each one of them, But in different functions.

Comment: Then add that logic to the question. Which method needs to access which element(s).

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I have updated my question, I hope this helps?

Comment: Your array contains a lot of objects which all have cities and postcodes, so what is your logic to choose a single city and postcode from it? (I am assuming you want only one from your example)

Comment: There will only be one of each element in the array, So one city, PostCode, Country...

Comment: Then why are you using an array? To access the first element in the array, you can use `array.first` which returns the first element of the array if it is available.

Comment: Are you displaying this data in list or something ?

Comment: @AhmedR. No, As per my question I simply want to take each of these elements and assign them to a label

Comment: @RakeshaShastri array.first simply outputs nil

Comment: That means there is nothing in the array. First add something to it.

Answer (score 1):

I may be totally reading the question wrong but in trying to read *into* your question, I think the terminology may be where clarification is needed; Object vs Array

An **object** has properties - lets examine the Details() object

```
var msgObj = Details()
```

which contains address information for *one* user. So conceptually this is how it would be represented in FireStore

```
users
  this_user
    address
      city: "some city"
      country: "some country"
      county: "some county"
      line1: "line one"
```

the 'documents' are the items stored within the address collection

```
  city: "some city"
  country: "some country"
  county: "some county"
  line1: "line one"
```

and your Details() object has properties that correspond to those documents and stores them as properties within the object; city, county etc

```
 msgObj.city = city
 msgObj.country = country
```

On the other hand, an **array** contains a series of **objects**, not properties. e.g. an array would generally **not** contain city, country etc, but it would contain a series of Details() objects and each of those Detail() objects has it's properties of city, country etc. For example, suppose you want to work with addresses of several different users - you would create a Details() object for each user, which contains their address information and append each one to an array.

```
self.dataArry[0] = the Details() objects of one user
self.dataArry[1] = the Details() object of another user
self.dataArry[2] = the Details() object of a third user
```

You could then, for example, display the users within a certain radius of this user, or send them all an email etc.

To answer your question, if you are working with a single users address information there is no need for an array, you can simply store it as a single Details() object variable within the class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myUserAddress = Details()

    func to get this users address documents from FireStore {
        if let city = msgdata["city"] as? String {
           self.myUserAddress.city = city
        }
        if let country = msgdata["country"] as? String {
           self.myUserAddress.country = country
        }
        //remember that the properties are only valid from here on
        //as FireStore is asychronous
        self.DisplayCity()
        self.DisplayLocation()
    }

    //and then later on when you want to display those properties
    func DisplayCity() {
      let city = self.myUserAddress.city
      print(city)
    }
    func DisplayLocation() {
      let lon = self.myUserAddress.logitude
      let lat = self.myUserAddress.latitude
      //show the location on a map via lon & lat
    }
```